# Spring XD - Change File Source directory at runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-xd

I would like to change configuration of a File Source at runtime. From what I see in docs and in source definition, directory is statically defined (i.e. no expressions), see [the bean definition](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/blob/master/modules/source/file/config/file.xml).

I know that using plain Spring Integration it's possible to call `setDirectory(...)` on inbound file channel adapter. Is there any way to do same thing in XD?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can call `setDirectory()` on the message source, beware that `auto-create-directory` (default `true`) won't work - the directory is created during bean creation. It will work for existing directories however.

One possibility to do what you want is to customize the file source to add a wrapper `MBean` that will delegate to the `FileReadingMessageSource.setDirectory()` You can get a reference to the bean using bean name `<adapterId>.source` (you would have to give the adapter an `id` attribute).

You could then change the directory over JMX (or by adding a control-bus to send a message to your wrapper - in which case you would need some other technology to get a message to the control bus - http, tcp, etc).

Comment: I was thinking about doing it without customizing source, now I see that it's ok, thanks.